# How to sort an array in a array by the length of the array?

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

I have an array which contains:

```
[['test3', ['7']], ['test4', ['1']], ['test', ['2', '4']], ['test1', ['2', '4']], ['test2', ['5']]]
```

I don't know how I can sort this by the length of the second item (= array) in the array of the full array.
It should look like this when it is sorted:

```
[['test4', ['1']],  ['test2', ['5']], ['test3', ['7']], ['test', ['2', '4']], ['test1', ['2', '4']]]
```

It would be also nice if somebody knew how to sort it also by the numbers in the array.

**The first item is not relevant.**

Comment: Because it would be nice if the sorting would also sort it by the numbers in the array ['test3', ['7']] ( => so the 7  in there)

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.
Sorting with a key is covered in any Python `sort` tutorial.  Please compete your research before posting a question here.

Comment: Sorry but I could not find anything :(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use a `key`, so you could you the following code:

```
l = [['test3', ['7']], ['test4', ['1']], ['test', ['2', '4']], ['test1', ['2', '4']], ['test2', ['5']]]
l.sort(key=lambda item: (len(item[1]), str(item[1][0])))
```

Comment: The output does not match the expected output in the question.

Comment: @Selcuk I updated the answer, I understood wrong before

Comment: Now your input list is rigged to match the output.

Comment: @Selcuk Yes, it there any problem in the output now, if I change the list, it will still work?

Comment: No, but your input is not the same as the question. You have modified the input so that it produces the correct output.

Comment: @Selcuk Oh, sorry, I copied the output list, instead of the input list, now I changed it

Comment: This works fine in the sorting with the length of the array, but is it possible to sort it also with the numbers in the arrays?

Comment: Yes: sorting it according to the first number (without taking into account the list lenght):
l.sort(key=lambda item: str(item[1][0]))

Comment: @Malo But that will mess up the current sorting

Comment: @AbhigyanJaiswal : well yes you can, but asks for it clearly, this use the length, then the first number  : l.sort(key=lambda item: (len(item[1]), str(item[1][0])))

Comment: @Malo Yes, I updated the answer